# Android - Spannable: Unable to set multiple spans at once

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring, spannablestringbuilder, android-spannable

I have the following code to set a color span on multiple subStrings of the same string.

```
fun getColoredText(text: String, @ColorInt color: Int, vararg coloredSubText: String): Spannable {

        val spannable = SpannableString(text)

        for (textToColor in coloredSubText) {

            val start = text.indexOf(textToColor)

            spannable.setSpan(
                ForegroundColorSpan(color),
                start,
                start + textToColor.length - 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
            )
            spannable.

        }

        return spannable
    }
```

I provide the following arguments:

```
getColoredText("This is my full length of the string", someColorValue, "my", "length")
```

But everything after `"my full length of the string"` gets colored. 
Could someone please help figure out what is wrong with the above method?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above code is fine. 
The issue was that i was trying to set clickable span on a spannable with color. And the clickable span overrides the other colors.
The way to set it as follows:

```
fun getClickableTextWithColor(spannable: Spannable, clickableText: String, @ColorInt color: Int, onClickListener: (View) -> Unit): Spannable {
        val text = spannable.toString()

        val start = text.indexOf(clickableText)
        spannable.setSpan(
            object : ClickableSpan() {
                override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                    onClickListener.invoke(widget)
                }

                override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                    super.updateDrawState(ds)
                    ds.color = color
                }
            },
            start,
            start + clickableText.length,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        return spannable
    }
```